# Problem with Named event of length 4*n-1using CreateEvent() and Openevent()

Tags: multithreading, winapi, events

I have two applications, one creates a named event using `CreateEvent()` and other opens the same event using `OpenEvent()`, as follows:

Application A.exe:

```
DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, (LPCWSTR)DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT);
if (GetLastError() != 0)
{
    DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE,(LPCWSTR)DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT);
}
else
{
    cout<<"DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT created"<<endl;
}
```

Application B.exe :

```
DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent =OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, (LPCWSTR)DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT);
if (GetLastError() != 0 && INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == m_DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent)
{
    DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, (LPCWSTR)DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT);
}
else
{
    cout<<"m_DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent opened"<<endl; 
}
```

The event name is defined in a common header file as below:

```
#define CS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT          "DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_MSG_TYPE"
```

Application A is able to create the event successfully, but Application B is not able to open the event, getting a handle value of NULL.

I have tested a few scenarios and came to know that if the event name is a length of 4*n-1 then the open event always gives me a NULL handle value, and if the event name is less then 4*n-1 or more than 4*n-1 then my application works fine.

Please help with why my application is behaving like this when the event name length is 4*n-1.

Other events created and opened in applications similarly as above are working fine as their lengths are not 4*n-1.

`CreateEvent()` and `OpenEvent()` should work on all the event lengths.

Comment: Shouldn't the define be: `#define CS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT _T("DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_MSG_TYPE")`

Comment: @user3161924 correct, though technically it should be using `TEXT()` instead of `_T()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LPCWSTR` typecasts are wrong. You can't cast narrow strings into wide strings like you are doing. Use a wide string literal to begin with, eg:

```
#define CS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT L"DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_MSG_TYPE"
...
CreateEventW(..., DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT);
...
OpenEventW(..., DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT);
```

That being said, using `CreateEvent()` and `OpenEvent()` the way you are is causing a race condition. Since it is clear that either application can create the event if it doesn't already exist, you should just use `CreateEvent()` in both applications and let it avoid the race condition for you. There is no reason to use `OpenEvent()` in this code at all.

Also, your error checking is wrong. Application A is not checking that a failure actually occurred before looking for a failure error code. `CreateEvent()` can report non-zero error codes in both success and failure conditions. Application B is at least trying to check if `OpenEvent()` failed, but it is doing so incorrectly since `OpenEvent()` returns `NULL` on failure, not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Try this instead:

Application A.exe and B.exe:

```
#define CS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT L"DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_MSG_TYPE"
...
DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent = CreateEventW(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT);
if (NULL == DLSRemoteConnnectionRqstEvent)
{
    // error handling...
}
else
{
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        cout << "DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT opened" << endl;
    else
        cout << "DLS_REMOTE_CONNECTION_RQST_EVENT created" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for correction. Can you please also let me know a specific reason why application B is failing to perform openevent() in case if event name length is exactly 4*n-1 . For other length more then 4n-1 or less then 4n-1 it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @ashishpatil there is no such length limitation. Your original code was passing invalid strings to the functions, and checking for failures incorrectly. The code I have given you should be working fine in both apps.